# Query relation images from Parse that uses Back4App database

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, back4app

So I have an ParseObject setup as this - This is the main Object in Parse called MGLocation:

```
struct MGLocation: ParseObject {
    var objectId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var originalData: Data?
    var ACL: ParseACL?
    var title: String?
    var category: String?
    init() {}
    init(objectId: String?) {
        self.objectId = objectId
    }
}
```

Then I have my Codable setup using the following code:

```
struct Place: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var b4aId = ""
    let title: String?
    let category: String
    init(
        id: Int,
        title: String?,
        category: String,
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.category = category
    }
    init(with p: MGLocation) {
        self.id = atomicId.wrappingIncrementThenLoad(ordering: .relaxed)
        self.b4aId = p.objectId ?? ""
        self.title = p.title ?? "Undefined"
        self.category = p.category ?? "Uncategorized"
    }
}
```

Then I have the following function which pulls in the MGLocation:

```
func fetchPlaces() {
    let query = MGLocation.query().limit(1000)
    query.find { [weak self] result in
        guard let self = self else {
            return
        }
        switch result {
            case .success(let items):
                self.places = items.map({
                    Place(with: $0)
                })
            case .failure(let error):
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Questions**:

What is the best way that I can pull in a relational column? Inside MGLocation, I have a related column called `images` which can access another object.

[image]

This calls MGImage which has the following columns:

id, title, column, mime

Does anyone know how I can infuse and pull in the related column also? All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Parse-Swift from here: https://github.com/netreconlab/Parse-Swift, as oppose to the parse-community one. I'm one of the original developers of Pase-Swift (you can see this on the [contributors list](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/graphs/contributors)) and [I don't support the parse-community version anymore](https://github.com/netreconlab/Parse-Swift/discussions/7). The netreconlab version is way ahead of the other in terms of bug fixes and features and you will get better and faster support from the netreconlab since I've been the one to address the majority of issues in the past.

> What is the best way that I can pull in a relational column? Inside MGLocation, I have a related column called images which can access another object.

I always recommend looking at the [Playgrounds](https://github.com/netreconlab/Parse-Swift/tree/main/ParseSwift.playground/Pages) for similar examples. The Playgrounds has [Roles and Relation](https://github.com/netreconlab/Parse-Swift/blob/main/ParseSwift.playground/Pages/12%20-%20Roles%20and%20Relations.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift) examples. Assuming you are using version `4.16.2` on netreconlab. The only way you can do this with your current relation on your server is like so:

```swift
// You need to add your struct for MGImage on your client
struct MGImage: ParseObject { ... }

struct MGLocation: ParseObject {
    var objectId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var originalData: Data?
    var ACL: ParseACL?
    var title: String?
    var category: String?
    var images: ParseRelation<Self>? // Add this relation
    /* These aren't needed as they are already given for free.
    init() {}
    init(objectId: String?) {
        self.objectId = objectId
    }
    */
}

//: It's recommended to place custom initializers in an extension
//: to preserve the memberwise initializer.
extension MGLocation {
  // The two inits in your code aren't needed because ParseObject gives them to you
}

//: Now we will see how to use the stored `ParseRelation on` property in MGLocation to create query
//: all of the relations to `scores`.
Task {
  do {
    //: Fetch the updated location since the previous relations were created on the server.
    let location = try await MGLocation(objectId: "myLocationObjectId").fetch()
    print("Updated current location with relation: \(location)")

    let usableStoredRelation = try location.relation(location.images, key: "images")
    let images = try await (usableStoredRelation.query() as Query<MGImage>).find()
    print("Found related images from stored ParseRelation: \(images)")
  } catch {
    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
}
```

If your `images` column was of type `[MGImage]` instead of `Relation<MGImage>` then you would be able to use `var images: [MGImage]?` in your `MGLocation` model and simply use `include` on your query. You can see more here: https://github.com/netreconlab/Parse-Swift/blob/325196929fed80ca3120956f2545cf2ed980616b/ParseSwift.playground/Pages/8%20-%20Pointers.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift#L168-L173

Comment: Thanks for this @CoreyB, I would then assume that Back4App which I am using, has the old outdated ParseSwift? I would have to find another alternative way to host a Database and utilize your Parse SDK since it does seem a lot better and way more updated.

Comment: You won’t need to change anything on your server as both SDKs send REST commands, your server won’t know the difference between the SDKs. You simply swap out on the client side and you are good to go.

Comment: Ohh that's awesome, doing that now! Thanks CoreyB!

Comment: Can you mark my response as the answer to your question?